# Filtering duplicates in ArrayList using only a subset of class's properties jdk1.6

Tags: java, guava, java-6

What is a recommended algorithm to filter duplicates from an ArrayList whereby the criteria to constitute a duplicate is come conditional operations on a subset of the SomeClass's properties? Additionally, the filtered collection must preserve the order of the remaining elements from the original list.

e.g.

```
public class SomeClass {
    private String a;
    private String b;
    private String c;
    private String d;
}
```

and duplicates are two instances in the list which:
have object1.getA().equals(object2.getb()). Members c and d are of no interest.

SomeClass is part of a third-party library and not modifiable as such.

Unfortunately, jdk1.6 is to be used, thus no streams available but guava is.

The class has a dozen String members and the list contains tens of millions of objects.

I looked into providing a Wrapper class to provide custom equals() and hashCode() and use this in LinkedHashSet<>, however, the operations come quite expensive on the garbage collection provided the additional objects.

Using a TreeSet with a Comparator is slightly better but additional iterations were needed to get the new Collection back into order.

I am interested in any other alternatives.

Comment: Your equality is not symmetric. ``o1.a == o2.b``?

Comment: "I looked into providing a Wrapper class to provide custom equals() and hashCode() and use this in LinkedHashSet<>, however, the operations come quite expensive on the garbage collection provided the additional objects." I think for a good answer to your question you need to provide more details. Algorithmically a Wrapper and LinkedHashSet seem perfect, so saying that it's "quite expensive" implies that your environment, problem size, and resource requirements should be listed as problem constraints, including the performance and issues with what you've tried so far.

Comment: Typically a more conventional approach would be to build a `Map<AandB, SomeClass>` instead of using a `Set`.

Comment: @JeanLogeart, why did you ask about that? The question doesn't mention that the algorithm isn't working, just that it's "quite expensive". It seems to me if the equality was not symmetric, the user would notice that that the result list contain duplicates or something like that.